# Import FindBugs configuration from Sonar to Maven

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, findbugs

How can I use a FindBugs configuration file from Sonar as the rule set in the [Maven FindBugs plugin](https://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/)?

Comment: Please be aware, that newer SonarQube version do not rely on FindBugs anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place your file, i.e. `findbugs-sonar.xml` in the src/main/resource folder and specify the path in your maven reporting settings like this:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <includeFilterFile>findbugs-sonar.xml</includeFilterFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```