# How to configure findbugs when using sonar with maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm calling sonar from maven:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

- How can I configure the findbugs rules?
- Do I have to configure the rules in maven as suggested in [Import FindBugs configuration from Sonar to Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502775/import-findbugs-configuration-from-sonar-to-maven)?
- Where can I find a documenentation how to write the configuration file?
- Is the configuration in sonar still relevant?
  The [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules) doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I configure the findbugs rules?

Use the SonarQube web GUI. Click on "Quality Profiles" in the black area at the top, then choose "Java". The Maven plugin will download your definitions from there and use them.

> Do I have to configure the rules in maven as suggested in Import FindBugs configuration from Sonar to Maven?

Nope. Configure them only in SonarQube, and you're all set.

> Where can I find a documenentation how to write the configuration file?

That would be the [FindBugs docs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/index.html). But you don't need to do that if you're using SonarQube.

> Is the configuration in sonar still relevant? The [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Rules) doesn't help.

Yes it is relevant. The SonarQube documentation is generally not very helpful, but configuring rules is quite straightforward using the GUI. You should have a good chance even without documentation.